# Microsoft Access 2013 developer tab missing

Tags: ms-office, ms-access-2013, office-2013

I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 where I can enable Developer tab on MS Word and Excel but the tab is missing in the Customize Ribbons option of MS Access as shown in the figure below:
[image]. It should be listed in the "Main Tabs" group but it's not available in any group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Developer" tab in Word and Excel was introduced (and hidden by default) to simplify the user interface for non-developers, which represent the vast majority of Word and Excel users. On the other hand, Access is much more widely used as a development tool so the "Developer" features are not relegated to a particular tab.

In other words, you can't see the "Developer" tab in Access because Access doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1):

It Isn't visible, but the features you're looking for are when you open form in Design view. There you have access to ActiveX controls, VBA modules and so on. I know this is an old thread, but I bumped into It, maybe It will be useful to someone.